# Interaction Trigger with condition

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, interaction

Is it possible to Invoke a command action conditionally?

Basically I have created a Custom control (DialogHeader) which I am going to use for all of my DialogWindow Headings.

In some of the DialogWindows I want to be able to close them using the Escape key and in others I don't.

I Updated my CustomControl definition to have the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseWithEscapeKeyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CloseWithEscapeKey), typeof(bool), typeof(DialogHeader),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnCloseWithEscapeKeyChanged));

public bool CloseWithEscapeKey
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(CloseWithEscapeKeyProperty);
    set => SetValue(CloseWithEscapeKeyProperty, value);
}

private static void OnCloseWithEscapeKeyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (d is not DialogHeader ctrl)
        return;

    ctrl.CloseWithEscapeKey = (bool)e.NewValue;
}
```

What I was hoping to do in the definition of the DialogHeader was add in:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:KeyTrigger Key="Escape">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{TemplateBinding CloseCommand}" />
    </i:KeyTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I have tried adding a CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding CloseWithEscapeKey}"to the InvokeCommandAction but this makes no difference.

Is there any way to hook this trigger up so it will only fire if my 'CloseWithEscapeKey' property is set to 'True' ?

Comment: All command objects have a `CanExecute` method which should be able to do what you want if you are able to pass relevant state to the command somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overthinking this, and all that I needed was this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <i:KeyTrigger Key="Escape">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseCommand}"
                               IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding CloseWithEscapeKey}" />
     </i:KeyTrigger>

</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```